# Drupal 7 - Editing Default Emails in user.module file

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, html-email

I have drupal 7 installed on my live server. I want to edit the default text emails to Html emails which are present in user.module file. I tried changing the core file, deleted cache, deleted browser cache, but it does not work. I have also changed the permission to 777, but it did not work.

I know it is not a good idea to change the default core files, but is it possible to change the drupal core files ??

Thanks

**Update**

I have installed Html mail module, and i can change the look of the html, however i wish to change the actual text of the default emails.

**Update 2**

As mentioned in the answer below, i tried checking the the settings page in Drupal, however i could not get the forget password email and new comment email text. Is it possible to add this or edit this using the HTML mail module??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the emails are being sent from the system and the content is editable as we want. To stylize the emails, i am using html mail module as suggested by CLive.

The new account creation, account cancellation emails can be found in "Account settings" page when you login as a admin.

All other emails are set from "Actions" settings page.

I could use html tags in the emails content, i think it worked because i was using html mail module.

I hope this comment helps someone trying to change the core email content from drupal.

Comment: Are us using SMTP authentication support module to send emails...?

Answer (score 4):

It is really simple.

Goto http://www.yourdomain.com/admin/config/people/accounts/settings
There is an "Emails" section in which you can edit all emails sent by the core user module.

Add [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module to be sure that Drupal will add the good headers and you are done !

Comment: Thanks DuaelFr, i did try that, but the forget password and new comment email text is missing in the settings page. Is it possible to change the content of the email using Html mail module???

Comment: HTML Mail module just allow Drupal to send emails with an HTML header. HTML email aloow you to define an email main template to provide your website en email layout. The content of emails is defined in the interface I linked in my post. You can put HTML in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, at the end of the day the Drupal core files are just plain old PHP. While it's an extremely bad idea to hack core files (it sounds like you already know why) all you'd need to do is change the code to do what you want it to do.

The good news though is that someone has already written a module to do what you want: [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail).

This module allows you to theme emails leaving the system as you would theme a normal Drupal site, and replaces the outgoing emails with those HTML versions per your settings.

Comment: Thanks Clive. I did install the html mail module, and i could change the look of the email, however is there any provision in this module to change the default text. thanks